# jQuery Mobile: Docytype and Header information required per page?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm starting to dive into jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to figure out how each page is supposed to be constructed...

Say I have an app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Demos and Documentation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="experiments/themeswitcher/jquery.mobile.themeswitcher.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home">
    <div id="jqm-homeheader">
        <h1 id="jqm-logo"><img src="docs/_assets/images/jquery-logo.png" alt="jQuery Mobile Framework" width="235" height="61" /></h1>
        <p>A Touch-Optimized Web Framework for Smartphones &amp; Tablets</p>
        <p id="jqm-version">Alpha Release</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/intro.html">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/features.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/platforms.html">Supported platforms</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I navigate to "docs/about/intro.html", does intro.html need to have all of the same document declarations as the main mobile app? In other words, `<head>`, `<script>`, `<link>`, etc... Do I need to declare every required script, style, and document type params as if it was an individual page being loaded on its on?

The reason I ask is from what I can see, the page doesn't actually get loaded... it's like it's loaded on top... you're not actually going to "docs/about/intro.html" ... I could be wrong.

Could someone kindly clarify this all for me?

Comment: I haven't had trouble loading in HTML fragments.  It should do that by default if you *don't* tag the link with `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"`.  Update your question with an example of the documents you're trying to link to (e.g. intro.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens (as per my understanding).

Taking your example, jQuery Mobile looks for "docs/about/intro.html", goes into it, and looks for the `<div data-role="page">`, ignoring everything else `<head>, <body>` etc.

It then brings that page div into your existing page and changes the URL to "#/docs/about/intro.html" (or something similar)

Comment: So in other words, stylesheets, scripts etc not required for the other pages.

Comment: That's what I gathered... why is this not explained within the documentation. Or maybe it is and I can't see it?

Comment: It's not explicitly mentioned. It does say the following: "The basic workflow with page loading is as follows: first, a page is requested with a normal HTTP request, and subsequent "pages" are then requested and injected into that page's DOM. Because of this, the DOM may have a number of "pages" in it at a time, each of which can be re-visited by linking to its data-url attribute." I figured out the rest by simply looking at the structure of the documentation itself (since it itself is written in jQuery mobile)

Comment: From the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) (which have been updated, mercifully, since this question): 

"any scripts and styles referenced the head of a page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax, but they will execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP. When scripting jQuery Mobile sites, both scenarios need to be considered."

Advice elsewhere in the answers that `<head>` elements are unnecessary on "subsequent" pages, is misguided.

Answer (score 2):

The way jquery mobile works, you must have any scripts and css in the head of the first page loaded. This can be demonstrated by going to the [scrollview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/) demos. If you can navigate to any page from there, you bring the scripts to enable scrollview with it, but if you refresh the page, you lose the functionality of the scripts

I would recommend putting the contents of head on *all* of your pages for the following reason - what happens if someone opens the 'about' page before they open home? You will get a fairly indecipherable web page.

Answer (score 1):

Look into what type of [Navigation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/content/../../docs/lists/../../docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html) you want as there are several different models/types

Comment: And that's the best answer here. A conclusion of mine: You don't need to put headers in subsequent sites as long as you can be sure that nobody tries to access them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for us, so far, I've seen a way to solve your dilemma is to build all the site in a single html page. I have not seen any documentation that explains how to efficiently build a website made ​​of multiple pages in a local environment, without losing the wonderful transitions jquerymobile.

Comment: Man, that seems gross... what a huge file that would result in. I'd rather not.

Comment: No there is a better way. Build the different pages in PHP files, sans `<head>` and `<body>` tags (page `<div>`s and associated child elements only) and include them into your main HTML using `include`. Slightly better than one massive HTML file and you could even do conditional `include` s

Comment: And as mentioned above, as long as pages are in the same domain, you get the transitions of jQuery mobile. You could have as many different .html files as you want

Comment: One downside of using PHP in this way is that the HTML resource in no longer "static". It may be an acceptable tradeoff, but the conceptual simplicity of having completely static HTML resources is a nice thing.